# SonarQube static code analysis report getting published on local sonar server not on remote sonar server

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

When I use this command on my local system the static code analysis report is generate perfectly on my local dashboard but when I am replacing it with the remote sonar url it always shows 0 bugs,0 vulnerabilities. 
Sonar server version is different for the two ; can it be the reason for this?
sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectKey=foo  -Dsonar.sources=. -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.projectName=bar -Dsonar.projectVersion=1

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the version is different it can be definitely the reason for the analysis to show different results, as analyzers which are used to analyze the code are downloaded from the server. Also your quality profile (i.e which rules are enabled) is defined by the server.

Comment: Update: it is working fine for one of my projects with remote sonar server but not for the other and both are in ruby language.  I am getting below stack trace on localhost with the project having this issue but still it pushes perfectly on localhost: ERROR: Failed to get Node.js version. No CSS files will be analyzed.
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "node": error=2, No such file or directory .   Logs on the remote sonar server does not have any errors but it does not publish coverage somehow!

Comment: @AkashJain this seems to be an unrelated problem, post a separate question, you can also use the community forum https://community.sonarsource.com/